# Flutter how can i get the value that from country code that i've been used from my app

Tags: flutter, dart, package, widget, country-codes

i got the code from pub.dev but its a bit complicated for me to understand when i try to get the value that on the ccp. this is the code what they give me

```
void _onCountryChange(CountryCode countryCode) {
    //TODO : manipulate the selected country code here
    print("New Country selected: " + countryCode.toString());
  }
```

how can i get the value and pass it to other place

i already implement the ccp that look like this

```
CountryCodePicker(
      initialSelection: "ID",
      favorite: ['+62', "ID"],
),
```

it works fine when i did the `onChange: print,` in the CountryCodePicker. they give the exact thing that i want

Answer (score 1):

you can have a string called picked country code, and on selectig a country code you call setstate and update its value.

```
String? pickedCountryCode;

void _onCountryChange(CountryCode countryCode) {
    //TODO : manipulate the selected country code here
    print("New Country selected: " + countryCode.toString());
setState(() {
        pickedCountryCode =countryCode.toString();
      });

  }
```

and then your country code picker

```
CountryCodePicker(
                onChanged: _onCountryChange,
                // Initial selection and favorite can be one of code ('IT') OR dial_code('+39')
                initialSelection: 'IT',
                favorite: ['+39', 'FR'],
                countryFilter: ['IT', 'FR'],
                // flag can be styled with BoxDecoration's `borderRadius` and `shape` fields
                flagDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: ah so i need to use setState fuction

Comment: nope the value still null

Comment: I have updated my answer to show where to put  `_onCountryChange`

Comment: what about if i want to gather the country code value and i will print them in a ontap gesture, i have an country code picker + textfield for my phone number authentication

Comment: the answer at the top work if, i changed the ccp first and click the button

Comment: in the ontap you can get it from  here `pickedCountryCode`

Comment: do mark as answer and leave an upvote if this helped you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244158/discussion-between-royalindo-and-griffins).